# Leer y manipular la primera línea de un archivo CSV con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

estoy creando un formulario donde hay una opción de cargar un archivo CSV con varios registros, el proceso resulta y me devuelve los campos de forma ordenada y listos para introducirlos en una base de datos.

El detalle es que necesito controlar el archivo que están subiendo, que los títulos e informaciones estén en orden, para mantener la estructura de mi base de datos, es decir yo doy una plantilla para el csv predefinida y **los titulos deben ser**:

```
nombre, apellido
```

Si el lo sube así:

```
apellido, nombre
```

Le rechazo la subida, en resumen se basa en leer el primer elemento de un array, el problema de la lectura de este array es que el indice siempre se devuelve por cada registro en el csv, por lo que evaluar el primer registro se me torna dificil.

Es decir, empieza el array desde el indice 0 hasta el 5, al leer toda esta celda, pasa a la otra y vuelve a empezar el indice en 0, por lo que leer el primer registro que seria el título del csv es lo que busco.

Archivo php:

```
<?php
$part = new csv();
$upload = $part->upload();
class csv {
    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'config.php';
        try{
        $this->BBDD = new PDO(PDO_HOSTNAME, PDO_USER, PDO_PASS);
        $this->BBDD->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE);
        $this->BBDD->exec(PDO_CHAR);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Error to connect with SQL Server" . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . " " . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
    public function upload(){
        $this->FILETYPE = $_FILES['FILE']['type'];
        $this->FILESIZE = $_FILES['FILE']['size'];
        $this->FILETMP = $_FILES['FILE']['tmp_name'];
        if(strcmp($this->FILETYPE, "application/vnd.ms-excel")==0 && ($this->FILESIZE < 10000) && (isset($this->FILETMP))){       
            $DATA = file($this->FILETMP);
            $flag = 1;
            foreach($DATA as $line => $key){
                if($flag!=0){
                    $CSV_DATA  = explode(";", $key);
                    $ROW  = array("param1" => $CSV_DATA[0]);
                    if(in_array("name", $ROW)){
                        echo "done"; // test
                    }else{
                        echo "fail";
                    }
                }
                $flag++;
            }
        }

    }
    private $BBDD;
    private $FILETYPE;
    private $FILESIZE;
    private $FILETMP;
}
```

Este código solo me lee la primera línea, pero al estar dentro del bucle me devuelve true la primera línea si el título esta bien, pero por el tema de los indices que se regresan por cada registro me dan false los demás.

Resultado:

```
done fail fail fail
```

Answer (score 3):

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte no esta escrito en clase pero basicamente el proceso ocurre dentro de tu primer if en la función upload

```
<?php
//obtenemos el archivo .csv
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type']; 
$tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$archivotmp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']; 

//cargamos el archivo
$lineas = file($archivotmp);
//inicializamos variable a 0, para hallar la primera línea
$i=0;

//Recorremos el bucle para leer línea por línea
foreach ($lineas as $linea_num => $linea)
{ 
   //abrimos bucle
   /*si es diferente a 0 significa que se encuentra en la primera línea 
   (con los títulos de las columnas) y por lo tanto puede leerla*/
   if($i == 0) 
   { 
       //abrimos condición, solo entrará en la condición la primera vez del bucle.
       /* La funcion explode nos ayuda a delimitar los campos, por lo tanto irá 
       leyendo hasta que encuentre un ; */
       $datos = explode(";",$linea);

       //Almacenamos los datos que vamos leyendo en una variable
       $nombre = trim($datos[0]);
       $edad = trim($datos[1]);
       $profesion = trim($datos[2]);

       // Verificas LOS NOMBRES

       //cerramos condición
   }
   $i++;
   //cerramos bucle
}
?>
```